# jest-expo-puppeteer - Getting "Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

When I run a very simple sample test in `jest-expo-puppeteer` following the guidelines in [jest-expo-puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/jest-expo-puppeteer), I keep getting a log of weird errors, and it seems none of the elements expected could be found. So I tried to print out the page:

```
// Import the config so we can find the host URL
import config from '../../jest-puppeteer.config'

let response

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Jest puppeteer exposes the page object from Puppeteer
  response = await page.goto(config.url)
})

it(`should have welcome string`, async () => {
  const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML)
  console.log(html)
  await expect(page).toMatchElement('div[data-testid="welcome"]', { text: 'Welcome!' })
})
```

The result of the page shows the text `Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.`:

```
...
      <body>
          <!-- 
            A generic no script element with a reload button and a message.
            Feel free to customize this however you'd like.
          -->
          <noscript>
            <form
              action=""
              style="background-color:#fff;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:9999;"
            >
              <div
                style="font-size:18px;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:24px;margin:10%;width:80%;"
              >
                <p>Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.</p>
                <p style="margin:20px 0;">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    style="background-color: #4630EB; border-radius: 100px; border: none; box-shadow: none; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; padding: 6px 16px;"
                  >
                    Reload
                  </button>
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </noscript>
          <!-- The root element for your Expo app. -->
          <div id="root"><div class="css-view-1dbjc4n r-flex-13awgt0 r-pointerEvents-12vffkv"><div class="css-view-1dbjc4n r-flex-13awgt0 r-pointerEvents-12vffkv"></div></div></div>
        <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
      
      </body></html>
...
```

This happens for both headless and in-browser execution.

So it looks like Javascript is turned off. The `page` object is created internally by `jest-expo-puppeteer`, so I wonder:

- **How to turn on JavaScript in `jest-expo-puppeteer`?**
- **Shouldn't this be turned on by default? Perhaps there is something that I missed out in my setup?**

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the answer myself:

- The content `Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.` is always present in react-native file. It seems to server as a backup (in case the browser indeed doesn't have JavaScript enabled it will be shown).
- Hence there is no need to turn on JavaScript. Indeed JavaScript is turned on by default.
- The reason why I wasn't able to detect elements in my page is because JavaScript execution has not finished. When I put in a wait statement then it works fine, for example this:

```
it(`should have welcome string`, async () => {
  const welcome = await page.waitForSelector('div[data-testid="welcome"]')
  const text = await (await welcome.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue()
  await expect(text).toMatch('Welcome!')
})
```